# How to check architecture needs before installing Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, architecture

I am planning on installing Ubuntu on my computer that already has windows on it. I have a x64 based processor and windows is also in 64 bit operating system.

By using the `uname -m`command in the Ubuntu OS I get that it is `x86_64` which I am guessing means that the Ubuntu I want to install also is a 64 bit operating system.

I have created an additional 20GB partition so all that is done too.

Is there anything else I should check before I install it or should it be fine to go ahead?

Comment: Go ahead and enjoy Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you are good to go. Just for reference you can see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) link that lists the requirements for installing Ubuntu.

To install Ubuntu alongside Windows have a look at the official [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) (and if you have Windows 8, look at [this tutorial](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) also). There are plenty of resources out there on this topic.

So, enjoy Ubuntu!